# Can't clear terminal screen using C on MacOS

Tags: c

I'm currently working through a tutorial writing a text editor in C. I've come to a point where I need to clear the console, however the escape code "\x1b[2j" does nothing on my machine. I'm using zsh + ohmyzsh inside of iTerm2 on MacOS, although I test the same program inside of bash on the default mac terminal and it also didn't work. I've provided a minimum example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("test text\n");
   printf("\x1b[2j");
}
```

With this program I'd expect the 'test text' line to dissappear immediately, however, it just prints the line and exits.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function write to `stdout`. And `stdout` is by default (when connected to a terminal) *line buffered*.

This means all you write will be temporarily stored in a buffer, and not actually written to the terminal device until the buffer is full, a newline is written (the *line* buffered thing) or the buffer is explicitly flushed.

You probably don't want to end your terminal escape sequence with a newline, so you need to explicitly flush `stdout` using the `fflush` function:

```
printf("\x1b[2j");
fflush(stdout);  // Force the terminal escape code to actually be written
```

---

Once you have fixed the flushing of the buffer, there's still another couple of potential problems...

First of all, if you run inside an IDE using the IDE's output window, then it might not be considered a terminal and so might not be able to handle such control sequences.

The second possible problem is if the IDE opens a new "proper" terminal window, which is closed on process exit. This is a problem because then the terminal window will be closed immediately and you might not have time to see the effect of the control code. To solve this problem you might want to add a delay to the exit of your program. A simple `sleep(2)` call will halt the program for two second, allowing you to see any possible effects.

Comment: Ok, I added fflush after aswell as a sleep but it still doesn't clear anything. And I'm still running inside iTerm2 with zsh. I've noticed that some other escape codes work, like changing the colour of text, which seems very odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

The "clear screen" escape sequence is `<esc>[2J` (uppercase J, you have used it lowercase)  Try this:

```
int main()
{
    write(1, "\033[2J", 4);
    return 0;
}
```

(the use of `write` instead of `printf` avoids the overhead of starting the `stdio` subsystem, and makes your program lighter)

Comment: still doesn't do anything with both these changes, I was actually using write in the proper program before I made this post with a smaller example